# TemplateDoesNotExist when running django app

Tags: python, django, django-templates

My django app is structured as below

```
home/damon/dev/me/myproject/
                        manage.py
                       /mytracker/
                                    __init__.py
                                    settings.py
                                    urls.py
                                    /monitor/
                                             /media/

                       /mymonitor/  
                                    __init__.py
                                    models.py
                                    views.py
                                    urls.py
                                    /templates/
                                                base.html
                                                home.html
```

In .bashrc I set `PYTHONPATH` as `/home/damon/dev/me/myproject/`

and in settings.py added these values for MEDIA_ROOT and TEMPLATE_DIR

```
MEDIA_ROOT = 'home/damon/dev/me/myproject/mytracker/monitor/media'

MEDIA_URL = '/site_media/'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
                'home/damon/dev/me/myproject/mymonitor/templates'
                 )
```

mytracker.urls.py has

```
url(r'',include('mymonitor.urls')),
    url(r'^site_media/(?P<path>.*)$','django.views.static.serve',{'document_root':settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
```

whereas mymonitor.urls.py has

```
...
 url(r'^$','mymonitor.views.home',
                    {'template_name':'home.html',
                     'page_title':'Home'
                     },
                    name='home'),
..
```

The base.html is extended by home.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
Your Home
{% endblock %}
```

I think the pythonpath,locations of files everything is correctly done..Still I am getting a TemplateDoesNotExist error

```
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version:     1.4
Exception Type:     TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    

[{'page_title': 'Home'}, {'csrf_token': <django...
```

The views.py has

```
def custom_render(request,context,template):
    req = RequestContext(request,context)
    return render_to_response(req)

def home(request,template_name,page_title):
    context = {'page_title':page_title}
    return custom_render(request,context,template_name)
```

I cannot figure out why this occurs.How do I diagnose this error..? Can someone please tell me?

Comment: add a `,` after `'home/damon/dev/me/myproject/mymonitor/templates'` in `TEMPLATE_DIRS`

Comment: Also, the template structure should be `/templates/mymonitor/home.html`

Comment: should n't the html files reside at the TEMPLATE_DIRS ?

Comment: not necessarily, it can reside in the app too as long as it is in `myapp/templates/myapp/files.html`

Comment: You don't have to modify `TEMPLATE_DIRS` as Django has `app_directories.Loader` enabled by default. Please, show the full stack trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `render_to_response(template)` instead of `render_to_response(req)`.

Here is a snippet from Django documentation:

```
return render_to_response('my_template.html',
                          my_data_dictionary,
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Also you have a *relative* path in `TEMPLATE_DIRS` when it should be *absolute* (that is, starting from a **slash**, like `/home/damon/...`). Because of this `filesystem.Loader` doesn't find your template.

---

And here is just an advice. [`TemplateResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/template-response/) is much more awesome and cool then old-school `render_to_response`.

Comment: sorry,was struggling with bad net connection.. I have put the stack trace at http://pastebin.com/DbUfKdw6  .. I have used absolute path in template dir

Comment: @damon well, no, code in your question and your stack trace show that the path is relative. Also `app_directories.Loader` is searching in `home/damon/dev/me/myproject/mymonitor/templates/` for some reason. Please, ensure that all paths start with a slash (like `/home/damon/…`).

Comment: Also I'd suggest unsetting `PYTHONPATH`. You shouldn't really touch it.

Comment: Oh and the most funny thing! The argument to `render_to_response` should be `template`, not `req`.

Comment: sorry ,that silly typo caused all this trouble!! sory again for wasting everyones' time

Answer (score 2):

1. You should not modify `TEMPLATE_DIRS` in this case, because [`app_directories.Loader`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/api/#django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader) (enabled by default) should do it for you, if you have your application in `INSTALLED_APPS`.
2. You probably forget '/' in the path in `TEMPLATE_DIRS` ('home/...' instead should be '/home/...')
3. Your `TEMPLATE_DIRS` as you have it now is just string (in parentheses where the parentheses are ignored here), it should be a `tuple` so you need to add comma after your path:

   ```
   TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
                   '/home/damon/dev/me/myproject/mymonitor/templates',
                   )
   ```